# Isolated points of the conjugate set

Tags: complex-analysis

If $\lambda_o$ is an isolated point of any closed subset $M$ of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, is it true that $\overline{\lambda_o}$ is isolated in the conjugate set $\overline{M} = \{\overline{\lambda} \in \mathbb{C}: \lambda \in M\}$?

Also is "closedness" of the set needed?

Comment: Conjugation is a isometry, so it preserves the property of being an isolated point of a set.

Comment: Thanks. So closedness of the set is not needed, right?

Comment: Yup, closedness is not necessary